# Problem with deploying my app in Netlify as i use the reducer function

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, netlify

I don't know, although my app works fine in my local machine. when I deploy the in Netlify, the count stops working, so I saw in Console that handleClick works, yet the count always stays zero. only when you click very fast on the increment, you get 1 as the count. and again it becomes 0 for the next time. but this is not a problem if I use only one state for all characters, so just useState. what could be the prolem. thank you in advance for your answer.

```
import React, {  useReducer } from 'react'
const initState = {
    barbarian: 0,
    archer: 0,
    giant: 0,
    goblin: 0,
    wizard: 0
}
const actionTypes = {
    increment: 'increment',
    decrement: 'decrement'
}
function reducer(count, action) {
switch (action.type) {

    case actionTypes.increment:
        {
            return {
                ...count,
                [action.name]: count[action.name]++
            }
        }

    case actionTypes.decrement:
        {
            return {
                ...count,
                [action.name]: count[action.name] > 0 ? count[action.name]-- : 0
            }
        }
    default:

        return count
}

}


export default function Count({ name, id }) {


const [count, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initState)
function increment() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch({
            type: actionTypes.increment,
            id: id,
            name: name
        })
        console.log(count[name])
        console.log(name)

    }, 500)

}

function decrement() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch({
            type: actionTypes.decrement,
            id: id,
            name: name
        })
    }, 500)
}

return (
    <div className='counter'>
        <button onClick={decrement} className='bg-info'>-</button>
        <p className='count'>{count[name]}</p>
        <button onClick={increment} className='bg-success'>+</button>
    </div>
)
}
```

[how it seems in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xiN8.png)

Comment: Looks like you are missing value for the `name`?
`name` is `undefined` and
`initState[undefined]` is `NaN`

Comment: I have defined the InitialState above, and Name I have as props. maybe I should say that it is still a part of a SPA with multiple components. the logic works fine in locale Machine but after Deploying in Netlify this problem appears.